# "New posts" on admin panel incorrectly takes into account tag excerpt/description

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-tools, posts

On [admin panel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin) I see the "6" in the "New Posts" column for myself (per month):

> [image]

<sub>* screenshot has been taken on Google-translated page from Russian to English</sub>

According the [summary on my profile page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=summary) I have only 2 answers and 0 questions posted since 9 September (one month ago). I have no deleted posts posted during the last month.

At the same time on the [list of posts in profile activity page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=activity&sort=posts) I have additional records for tag excerpt/description. So looks like the count on admin table also reflect that. But tooltip says clearly "questions and answers created". This is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: Did you create tags? Added wiki excerpts? Sent mod messages?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard mod messages is a different column. Tags - yes, but tooltip explicitly says about "questions and answers". Nevertheless in profile section all of them stated as "[posts"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%87%ce%bf%ce%bb%cf%85%cf%84?tab=activity&sort=posts). So, yeah, looks like the tag descriptions count as well.

Comment: If you created four tag descriptions then yes, we probably caught the bug, better edit to reflect this e.g. "New Posts count also take into account tag descriptions". I can see the reason, it's because tag wiki are also stored in same table as posts.